# MobileFirst Foundation Hybrid Application integration with Bluemix push

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

MobileFirst 6.3, or 7.0

I've reviewed the hybrid, and native tutorials on DevWorks, and wanted to get clarification on a few points integrating with BlueMix push service.

Considering a hybrid app (iOS, Android) developed with MFP studio is the hybrid app dependent on the MFP server to subscribe to the provider (BlueMix)?

If the hybrid app is dependent on MFP server to subscribe, will push notifications destined for the device have to be delivered through the MFP server via adapter, or will they be sent directly to the device?

In general I'm trying to understand the minimum role the MFP server can play in developing a hybrid application that will receive BlueMix push notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, at this time, you cannot use a MFPF-based Hybrid app with the iOS 8-only push notification capabilities that originate from the Blumix Push service.

Also, MFPF adapters do not, at this time, work with Bluemix.

All in all, if you use MFPF, you use the unified push support as supplied and supported in MFPF. If you use Bluemix, that's a different approach to push.

Also, please add links to your questions next time - we shouldn't google/guess those...